# Typescript compile Error: TS2339:Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am stuck at the part that typescript compiling keeps failing.

Here is the code:

```
    (currentCellData.ellipsis && currentCellData.renderValue.props.children ? (
            <NTooltip key={index} title={currentCellData.renderValue} arrow placement="top-start">
              {renderTableCell}
            </NTooltip>
          ) : (
            <Fragment key={index}>{renderTableCell}</Fragment>
          ))
```

and this is the data of `renderValue` and the type.

[image]

```
declare type TValue = {
    renderValue: string | React.ReactElement;
    onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLTableCellElement>) => void;
    ellipsis?: boolean;
};
```

I want to get the value of `children` in `props` property inside `renderValue`.

However, when I activate typescript compiling, it fails and gives message

```
src/components/NTableBody/index.tsx:110:68 - error TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I think the issue is the string definition in `renderValue` type. However string definition is also needed for other component.

How can I solve or bypass this type issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears renderValue has union type of `string | React.ReactElement` and basically you need to narrow down the type before actually using it, obviously in this case you need to check if `renderValue` is an `React.ReactElement` before using its properties.

A suggestion is to simply check if it's not a string then it is `ReactElement` by using `typeof` keyword as following:

```
const {renderValue} = currentCellData;
typeof renderValue !== 'string' && renderValue.props.children
```